# Three way join in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, c#-4.0

I am trying to create an NHibernate mapping to the following tables:

```
AutomatedTestSequence - SequenceID, SequenceName
TestStep - StepID, StepDisplay
StepSequenceMapping - SequenceID, StepID
TestParameters - SequenceID, StepID, ParamID, ParamName, ParamValue
```

My classes and mapping are as follows:

```
public class AutomatedTestSequence
{
    public virtual int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual IList<TestStep> StepsList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

and the mapping is:

```xml
<class name="AutomatedTestSequence" table="AutomatedTestSequence">
  <id name="Id" column="SequenceID"/>
  <property name="Name" column="SequenceName"/>

  <bag name="TestStep" table="StepSequenceMapping" cascade="none" lazy="false">
    <key column ="SequenceID" />
    <many-to-many class="TestStep" column="StepID" />
  </bag>
</class>
```

Second class is:

```
public class TestStep
{
    public virtual int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string Display
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual IList<StepParameter> StepParameterList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

and the mapping is:

```xml
<class name="TestStep" table="TestStep">
  <id name="Id" column="StepID"/>
  <property name="Display" column="StepDisplay"/>

  <bag name="TestParameters" table="TestParameters" cascade="none" lazy="false">
    <key column ="StepID" />
    <many-to-many class="TestParameters" column="ParameterId"/>
  </bag>
</class>
```

Third class is:

```
public class StepParameter
{
    public virtual int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

and the mapping is:

```xml
<class name="TestParameters" table="TestParameters">
  <id name="Id" column="ParamID"/>
  <property name="Name" column="ParamName" />
  <property name="Value" column="ParamValue" />
</class>
```

My problem is, that the parameter is connected to a specific step in a specific automated test sequence (for example I have a parameter named `StartDate` it can have the value `7AM` for step `Open Application` in automated sequence `Morning Sequence`, and the value `7PM` for step `Open Application` in automated sequence `Evening Sequence`), but in the current mapping that I have the parameter is connected to the step no matter to which automated test sequence it belongs to. How do I change my mapping in order to include the automated test sequence id when mapping the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this classstructure is fixed. If not consider this:

```
public class AutomatedTestSequence
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ParameterDictionary> StepParameters { get; set; }
}

public class TestStep
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Display { get; set; }
}

public class ParameterDictionary
{
    public virtual AutomatedTestSequence Sequence { get; set; }
    public virtual TestStep Step { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// dictionary with paramtername/value pairs
    /// </summary>
    public virtual IDictionary<string, string> Parameter { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as ParameterDictionary;
        return (other != null) && (Sequence == other.Sequence) && (Step == other.Step);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Sequence.GetHashCode() ^ Step.GetHashCode();
    }
}


class AutomatedTestSequenceMap : ClassMap<AutomatedTestSequence>
{
    public AutomatedTestSequenceMap()
    {
        Id(seq => seq.Id, "AutomatedTestSequence");

        Map(seq => seq.Name, "SequenceName");

        HasMany(seq => seq.StepParameters)
            .Table("StepSequenceMapping")
            .KeyColumn("SequenceID");
    }
}

class TestStepMap : ClassMap<TestStep>
{
    public TestStepMap()
    {
        Id(step => step.Id, "StepID");

        Map(step => step.Display, "StepDisplay");
    }
}

class ParameterDictionaryMap : ClassMap<ParameterDictionary>
{
    public ParameterDictionaryMap()
    {
        Table("StepSequenceMapping");

        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(spmap => spmap.Sequence, "SequenceID")
            .KeyReference(spmap => spmap.Step, "StepID");

        HasMany(spmap => spmap.Parameter)
            .Table("TestParameters")
            .KeyColumns.Add("SequenceID", "StepID")
            .AsMap("ParamName")
            .Element("ParamValue");
    }
}
```

if you can't or dont want to use FluentNHibernate let me know and i post the xmlmappings.

remarks: `ParamID` ist really needed, if it is autogenerated in the database then fine, if set programmaticly then the code above has to be tweaked.

hope this helps

EDIT: the xml mappings

```
  <class mutable="true" name="AutomatedTestSequence" table="`AutomatedTestSequence`">
    <id name="Id" type="System.Int32" column="SequenceId">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" type="System.String">
      <column name="SequenceName" />
    </property>
    <bag name="StepParameters" table="StepSequenceMapping" mutable="true">
      <key>
        <column name="SequenceID" />
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="ParameterDictionary" />
    </bag>
  </class>

  <class mutable="true" name="TestStep" table="`TestStep`">
    <id name="Id" type="System.Int32" column="StepID">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Display" type="System.String">
      <column name="StepDisplay" />
    </property>
  </class>

  <class mutable="true" name="ParameterDictionary" table="StepSequenceMapping">
    <composite-id mapped="false">
      <key-many-to-one name="Sequence" class="AutomatedTestSequence" column="SequenceID"/>
      <key-many-to-one name="Step" class="TestStep" column="StepID"/>
    </composite-id>
    <map name="Parameter" table="TestParameters" mutable="true">
      <key>
        <column name="SequenceID" />
        <column name="StepID" />
      </key>
      <index type="System.String" column="ParamName"/>
      <element type="System.String" column="ParamValue"/>
    </map>
  </class>
```

Comment: I was hoping to keep the same class structure since it truly represents my domain, and a better software design in my opinion. 
I am willing to change my tables although I think that the ERD is also normalized  correctly, and I don't see how this can be changed.

If NHibernate doesn't support that I will probably need to have some kind of implementation as you suggested. But I was hoping there is another solution.

( I am using NHiberate and not FluentNHibernate)

Comment: @Yael in this class structure the information to which sequence the step belongs to isnt there, no backreference. even with plain SQL you cant get them individually, only as a whole. Same with parameterobjects. When you have a specific parameterobject you dont know where it belongs to. IMO the parameter belongs to the sequence and step combination not the steps alone. Can you show me use cases, so i can come up with a better solution?

Comment: Can you please attach the xmlmappings?